# How to map between two site collection lists using SharePoint online?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint 2013 online  - I have a list A in Site Collection A and I want to display the List A in another Site collection called Site Collection B.

I want When the master list is updated, it should automatically updated in another site collection list using JavaScript.

Please give me the help..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For JS only, an idea would be to have the list be updated via an InfoPath form.  When the user submits the InfoPath form to update the list, set a rule to jump to a SharePoint page that is running JSOM.  That JSOM page would update the lists with JavaScript and then return to the list view.
I've used a method like this when external CSOM wasn't desired.

Another way would be to use a CSOM .Net app on the side that syncs the lists every so often, but it sounds like you don't want to go that route.